# Does anyone know how to receive data from a 1d barcode scanner?

Tags: usb, serial-port, barcode-scanner

I am using a yhd-M300C 1D barcode scanner, it connects by a usb cable but it comes with no drivers so the computer doesn't recognize it. I am using Ubuntu 22.04

The scanner comes with a bunch of code you can scan from the manual to change it's settings, I can confirm these work as I was able to enter into settings and change the sound the scanner makes when it scans something.

From the instruction manual there is a reference to something called USB Conversion Function with two options: `USB Virtual Keyboard` and `USB Virtual Serial Port`. The way I was expecting this to work is by the virtual keyboard method, anytime it scans something the computer would perceive it as a keyboard stroke. I have tried putting the scanner into both modes but the computer still does not see any devices, at least nothing pops up when I use `lsusb` or `hardinfo`

Is there a way I can check if maybe it is somehow connected via serial cable, so it would be recognized as some other type of device? I know nothing about serial ports or cables, if there is anything else I can provide to help troubleshoot please let me know, help very much appreciated!

Comment: If it's a virtual keyboard, does anything come through if you scan something while in text editor?

Comment: Does `dmesg` show anything when you run it just after connecting the device?

Comment: @squillman I just tried setting it to USB Virtual Keyboard mode, it makes a beep when it scans something but nothing gets printed to the text editor

Comment: @Bodo I tried using ```dmesg -wH``` but I didn't notice any changes as I plugged the scanner in and out, other than it making a beep. Worth adding there is to much information so could be I missed it

Comment: @frend123123 unplug it, plug it back in and then copy the last 30 or so lines from `dmesg` into your question. Chances are it is there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Do I understand right that *the scanner* beeps when it is connected, not the PC? This might be a reaction to powering it.  Did you try different USB ports? Can you plug it to a Windows PC to see if something happens there?

Comment: I will edit the question to provide the outputs from dmesg, but I feel like it is alot of dense information few want to sift through, is there a way I could maybe copy these outputs to temporary files, and compare them?

@Bodo to confirm it beeps when it has power, different beeps for when changing settings, and another different beep for when it is scanning stuff. I was able to change the sound level of that third beep, so I know it is at least working somewhat

Comment: I have tried the beeper with several different computers, Windows and Linux environments but nothing can detect it is plugged in

Comment: See if you can find a driver, if for nothing else then on Windows. Your scanner might need one to translate USB-speech to Keyboard speech.

Comment: also: The manual might have barcodes to scan for setting it up (this is the case for some Datalogic scanners)

Comment: @Hannu on the manufacturer website they have drivers only available for the 2d scanners, the 1d scanners come with no drivers. And yes I downloaded their manual, which is how I can either put it into ```USB Virtual Keyboard``` or ```USB Virtual Serial Port``` mode. It was also how I changed the sound level of the beep, so I know the manual I have is correct

Comment: See if you can find a "SDK" kit for it, especially the serial port mode might require it. Virtual keyboard on the other hand should really be similar to having an extra USB-keyboard.

Comment: @frend123123 Please [edit] your question and add all information to the question. You could run `dmesg > file1`, then connect the scanner, then run `dmesg > file2` and use a file compare tool, e.g. `meld file1 file2` or diff -uw file1 file2`. How do you change the settings? If the scanner is supposed to work without a driver and if the OS does not show a (possibly unknown) device, then there is the possibility of a hardware defect. Assuming only the power wires of the USB port are connected but not the data wires, the device may beep and light up when it is connected without talking to the PC.